# How can I input more than one value in an element of a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, matrix

I have the following code

```
import numpy
import random
import pandas
wsn = numpy.arange(1, 6)
taskn = 3

t1 = numpy.random.randint(30, 200, size=len(wsn))
t2 = numpy.random.randint(30, 200, size=len(wsn))
t3 = numpy.random.randint(30, 200, size=len(wsn))

print('\nGenerated Data:\t\n\nNumber   \t Task 1  \t   Task 2  \t   Task 3\n')
ni = min(len(t1), len(t2), len(t3))
for i in range(ni):
    print('\t {0}    \t   {1}    \t    {2}  \t\t {3}\n'.format(wsn[i], t1[i], t2[i], t3[i]))
print('\n\n')
```

it prints the following

```
Number       Task 1        Task 2      Task 3

     1         167          101          64

     2         140          194          102

     3         85           139          42

     4         85           152          170

     5         96           43           83
```

I want to each element to have two values or three, so the output can be like

```
Number        Task 1        Task 2        Task 3
              1     2       1    2        1    2
     1       167   20       101  10      64   50

     2       140   80       194  20      102  88
 
     3       85    12       139  15      42   99

     4       85    11       152  66      170  66

     5       96    30       43   99      83   36
```

or is there a better structure to do this? cause am gonna use the values later in multiple functions so the access to each one of them should be possible

Comment: Create [two dimensional arrays](http://www.math.buffalo.edu/~badzioch/MTH337/PT/PT-multidimensional_numpy_arrays/PT-multidimensional_numpy_arrays.html) and the generate random ints by applying a [function on the axis of the array](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html).

Comment: I just didn't add the printing part, for the pandas I added it in the case there could be a solution made using it @MichaelSzczesny